# data.table: Keep original column name when applying a function inside a 'by=variable' statement

Tags: r, data.table

When I want to perform a function over one or multiple columns inside a `data.table` while modifying the columns I group by with a function in the same call, the resulting `data.table` always shows the applied function as the new column name.

Code example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(value=rnorm(100), class=sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE))

dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=factor(class)]
```

Output:

```
   factor   class_mean
1:      2  0.007297291
2:      3 -0.122847460
3:      1  0.103293676
```

What I originally would expect is that I get the original column name in the result, like this:

```
   class   class_mean
1:      2  0.007297291
2:      3 -0.122847460
3:      1  0.103293676
```

As far as I can judge, this is happening regardless of which function is applied to the grouping column(s). When performing grouped modifications on a `data.table` with a column name stored in another variable I usually use `by=get(variable_that_stores_the_column_name)`, also resulting in the modified `data.table` showing `get` as the new column name.

How can I modify my `data.table` grouping call to get the result I want without tediously renaming the column names of the result again?

#### EDIT:

Thanks for the responses and answers in the comments. This works for the most cases. However, if I would like to address the grouping variable by name via another variable (and want to keep that variable name in the result), the same problem arises:

```
var_name <- "class"
dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=.(var_name = factor(get(var_name)))]
```

names the resulting column `var_name`. And

```
var_name <- "class"
dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=.(get(var_name) = factor(get(var_name)))]
```

leads to an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=.(get(var_name) ="
```

Comment: `dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=.(class = factor(class))]` ?

Comment: `dt[, .(class_mean = mean(value)), by = .(class = factor(class))]`

Comment: FYI, I don't know of any R function that accepts `get(.) =`, i.e., a function call on the LHS of an assignment. If there is one, it is likely that it is working NSE (non-standard evaluation), and is using (perhaps _mis-using_) the `LHS = RHS` nomenclature for something clever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your edited question,

```
my_name <- "class"
dt[, .(class_mean=mean(value)), by=.(var_name = factor(var_name)), env = list(var_name = my_name)]
```

results in the desired output

```
    class  class_mean
   <fctr>       <num>
1:      2 -0.07004949
2:      1 -0.10250014
3:      3 -0.09003567
```